# Need a JavaScript Simple Code For Zip A Folder

Tags: javascript, html, zip, jszip, zip.js

my web server is a simple html server.
there is no node.js,no php
so i wanna make a zip file by js of the directory "/public_html/alpha"
mainly i wanna zip the alpha folder

I tried the jszip.js and zip.js but didnt work.why i dont know..

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/jszip.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<p>Works on firefox, chrome , opera &gt;= 15 and IE &gt;= 10 (but NOT in compatibility view).</p>
<button id="blob" class="btn btn-primary">click to download</button>

<script>


var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("readme.txt", "alpha");


jQuery("#blob").on("click", function () {
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function (blob) { // 1) generate the zip file
    saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");                          // 2) trigger the download
}, function (err) {
    jQuery("#blob").text(err);
});
});


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**This Code dont even give any result.**

Server link : [For Check Click Here](https://shakil.saifur.xyz)

Comment: The js you are trying to write runs on the client's machine, and not on your server. The clients machine does not have access to file on your server, unless you send a fetch request to it. So this code won't be able to locate readme.txt and others, which is why it doesn't work

Comment: so how can i do that?

Comment: You will have to have some sort of a backend, which can access files on your server. Once you do set that up (PHP, node etc), then you'll need to write a route/file that will zip your folder and send it as a response to the client

Answer (score -1):

Add jquery on header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then in script make it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#blob").click(function(){
    // bla bla bla your code
  });
});
```

Comment: added header

change it and it looks like this

`<script>


 var zip = new JSZip();
 zip.file("readme.txt", "alpha");



$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#blob").click(function(){
   zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function (blob) { // 1) generate the zip file
        saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");                          // 2) trigger the download
    }, function (err) {
        jQuery("#blob").text(err);
  });
});


</script>`

Comment: @ShakilAhmed You should keep an eye on the Developer tools' console. It will show you that you have a syntax error.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @ShakilAhmed Yes, your brackets/parentheses don't add up. Properly formatting your code will show this. (There are plenty of tools that can do this for you, also build in to most IDE's.)

Comment: Yes you have syndax error. and to use saveAs function you need filesaver here is a cdn : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js

try to put it in your header and try that one: 

var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("readme.txt", "alpha");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#blob").click(function() {
        zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(function(blob) {saveAs(blob, "hello.zip")})
    })
})

Comment: i edit it for zip the alpha directory..and there are some file in alpha directory
`var zip = new JSZip();
zip.folder("alpha");
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#blob").click(function() { 
        zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "hello.zip")
            
        })
        })
        })`
but zip just give me a alpha directory with no file